# Symfony 5: I can't login after logout

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I am working with Symfony 5 with Easyadmin 3, but I have a problem.

Using Security Bundle and a make: auth, i set up a login and I can log in normally, the problem is that once I log out, I can't log in again with the same user unless i edit it.

**src/Security/LoginFormAuthenticator:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\Persona;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\PasswordAuthenticatedInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Persona::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('No se encontro cuenta con ese Email.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
    {
        return $credentials['password'];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        return new RedirectResponse('admin'); //Ni bien se loguee donde ira
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

**src/Controller/SecurityController:**

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Controller;
    
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
    
    class SecurityController extends AbstractController
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
         */
        public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
        {
            // if ($this->getUser()) {
            //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
            // }
    
            // get the login error if there is one
            $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
            // last username entered by the user
            $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
    
            return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
        }
    
        /**
         * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
         */
        public function logout()
        {
            throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
        }
    }
```

**Config/Package/Security.yaml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: bcrypt
        App\Entity\Persona:
            algorithm: auto

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Persona
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                target: /login
                #target: app_any_route

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: I would somehow bet on something weird like ... the login form being cached (->wrong csrf-token) or not actually being logged out. the first can actually be checked by clearing the cache (symfony cache and possibly browser cache) after logout. the second can be checked via the profiler (which shows the logged in user) ... finally your setup might be relevant ... do you run via `symfony run` or `bin/console server:run` on command line or do you have nginx or something running?

Comment: I am new and the truth is I do not understand the idea, could you be a little more specific?

Comment: What you edit exactly and you can enter in your system after that? @Jakumi ask for more environment specifications and add some errors in your question.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm encoutering the same on the heroku platform. Not in local. @Jakumi, do you have an idea where it could come from ? 
If necessary, I'll make a new question.

Comment: @Pax auth is notoriously complicated as it is, I'm not even familiar with heroku and not confident I could really help. debugging this stuff is a lot of looking at requests, cookies, sessions and caches. So far I have no reliable strategy for helping someone ... and it's been a while...